# I am getting an error create is missing in typeof

Tags: angular, typescript

> Property 'create' is missing in type 'typeof import("D:/Project once more/examfrontend/node_module
> s/@types/ckeditor__ckeditor5-build-classic/index")' but required in type 'EditorConstructor'.

```
35                       <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" data="Hello"></ckeditor>
```

I am getting is error. I do not know where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Declear the Editor type as any will resolve this issue:

```
public editor:any = ClassicEditor;
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved actually I was having restricted properties in my tsconfig.json file

```
"strictInjectionParameters": true,
"strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
"strictTemplates": true
```

I removed those and got the output.

Comment: This will work. But it will cost real time error management on template